# Play Framework: No @javax.persistence.Id field found in class

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, persistence

I have this Play Model class that I'm trying to modify an object of, and when I want to save it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No @javax.persistence.Id field found in class [class models.Contact]
at play.db.ebean.Model._idAccessors(Model.java:39)
at play.db.ebean.Model._getId(Model.java:52)
```

The class:

```
@Entity
public class Contact extends Model implements Person {//, Comparable<Contact>{

private Long id;

private Client client;

@Required
private String email;

private String profil_picture;

private Boolean active = new Boolean(true);

private Boolean favorite = new Boolean(false);

@Transient
private Boolean profile_pic_url_init = new Boolean(false);
@Id 
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="client_id") 
public Client getClient(){
    return client;
}
public void setClient(Client client){
    this.client= client;
}
@Column
public Boolean getFavorite() {
    return favorite;
}
public void setFavorite(Boolean is_favorite) {
    this.favorite = is_favorite;
}
....
}
```

The code calling the save() method:

```
        List<Contact> contacts_list = current_client.getContacts();
        for (Contact c : contacts_list) {
            c.setFavorite(false);
            c.save();
        }
```

The class actually has an @Id annotation, so any guesses of why this doesn't work? I tried looking it up on google, but couldn't find much about this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure this is the actual cause of the problem, but I would bet on it: Place all the JPA annotations either on fields, or on getters, but don't put some on fields and some on getters.

Comment: Move `@Id` annotation to `id` fiekd instead of it's getter. BTW is there any particular reason why you don't want to follow Play's way with public model fields? Play relly on this approach on many places, and if you decide to do not use it, you can just also start common Java app instead

Comment: Yup, that fixed it, thanks a lot! But what is the actual reasoning behind it? @biesior No, no particular reason. Most of this code I actually inherited from the previous developer, I was just introducing a new feature that was, among others, supposed to update a field in the database, and stumbled upon this error.

Comment: rgr, just find your own way to the Play in such case, can't argue with other dev, but Play has decided to use other approach ;)

Comment: @biesior yes, but on the parts that I'm actually writing from scratch, I try to follow the Play conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `@Id` annotation to `id` field instead of its getter.